# How to split a table into a specific number of rows and columns on each page when printing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table with 3 columns and 100 rows. The cells are numbered from 1 until 300. How do I split the table into 3 columns and 10 rows on each page when printing?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting page breaks at every 10 lines.

Enter page break preview by clicking in the icon circled below.

Then drag the dotted blue lines up to every 10 rows.

Hit Ctrl + P to get a print preview, you will see each page is set to the page break lines you selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From memory, so a "general mode" description:

1. Prepare to record a macro; enable and select the "Developer" tab.
2. Select "Use relative references" in the Developer tab.
3. Place the cursor on the top left cell for a page.
4. Click "Record a new macro"
5. Use the CURSOR KEYS while holding the SHIFT key to select the cells to print on ONE PAGE
6. Hold CTRL and hit P, for printing -> the dialog opens.
7. Select options to print ONLY THE SELECTED CELLS, and how to place them on the page
8. PRINT
9. Use cursor keys to move the cursor into upper left position of NEXT page.
10. Stop recording.

Run the Macro, once for each page you wish to print.

*UNTESTED, may need to be amended, even so within the code of the generated macro*